# Railroad oriented programming in clojure

Tags: clojure

I saw a talk about railroad oriented programming (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYo3LN9Vf_M), but i somehow do not get how to work this out, if i use `reduce`, because `reduce` has two or even three arguments.

How am i able to to put the following code like a railroad? I seems to me hard, because of reduce taking a function as an argument in addition to the game object.

```
(defn play-game-reduce []

  (let [game-init
        (->>
         (io/initialize-cards-and-players)
         (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
         (announce))

        play-round
        (reduce play-card (assoc-in game-init [:current-trick] '()) [:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4])]

    (reduce play-round game-init (range (get game-init :round-count)))))
```

The whole code is here:
https://github.com/davidh38/doppelkopf/blob/master/src/mymain.clj

The code should more look like this:

```
(->> (io/initialize-cards-and-players)
             (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
             (announce)
    reduce (play-round .. )
    reduce (play-card ...))
```

That would look to me much more explicit.

Comment: Can you please update the question with expected output?

Comment: Can you post definitions for  `io/initialize-cards-and-players`, `shuffle-and-share-cards`, `myio/myshuffle`, `announce` and so on? If these are long, at least add a link to Github repository with this project. Can you describe what this code should do and what are `:current-trick`, `:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4` or `:round-count`?

Comment: @MartinPůda It is just a game object with cards. p1 - p4 are the players. *Current trick* holds the cards in a list, that are on the playing table. Round counts is the number of rounds the game will be played. I should really improve on naming, thank you.

Comment: That talk is about how to program in a strongly statically-typed language where function calls are the only form of control flow which is not true in Clojure.

Comment: @JaredSmith So, what else is possible in clojure?

Comment: Clojure has exceptions, you don't have to use monads like Either. You can certainly [mimic those patterns in a dynamic language](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land), but usually we don't. Whether that's good or bad depends on point of view :)

Answer (score 3):

That video was made for a different language and you can't directly transfer these ideas to Clojure.

I looked at your source code and there are some things to improve:

```
(defn play-card-inp []
  (eval (read-string (read-line))))
```

You shouldn't use [`eval`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval) in production code.

[`Read-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) is unsafe and you should use [`clojure.edn/read-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string) instead. I'm not sure what is expected input here and what is the result of the evaluation, maybe you should use just [`clojure.edn/read`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read) here.

```
(defn myshuffle [cards]
  (shuffle cards)
  )

(defn initialize-cards-and-players []
  ; init cards
  (def cards '([0 :c], [1 :c],[2 :c], [3 :c], [0 :s], [1 :s], [2 :s], [3 :s]))
  (def players '(:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4))

  ;(def round-players (take 4 (drop (who-won_trick tricks) (cycle (keys players)))))
  ; mix and share cards
  {:players (zipmap players (repeat  {:cards () :tricks ()}))
   :current-trick ()
   :round-start-player :p1
   :cards cards
   :round-count (/ (count cards) (count players))
   :mode ""
   })
```

You should delete `myshuffle` and use directly `shuffle` where needed. Ending parenthesis shouldn't be on a separate line.

Don't use `def` (creates global variable) inside `defn`, use [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) (creates local variables). I would rewrite this as:

```
(defn new-deck []
  (for [letter [:c :s]
        number (range 4)]
    [number letter]))

(defn new-game []
  (let [cards (new-deck)
        players [:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4]]
    {:players (zipmap players (repeat {:cards () :tricks ()}))
     :current-trick ()
     :round-start-player :p1
     :cards cards
     :round-count (/ (count cards) (count players))
     :mode ""}))
```

Notes for `mymain.clj`:

```
(defn who-won-trick [trick]
  (eval (read-string (read-line))))
```

Some unused function, same problems as above.

```
(defn share-card-to-player [game players-cards]
  (assoc game
         :players
         (assoc
          (get game :players)
          (first players-cards)
          (assoc (get (game :players) (first players-cards))
                 :cards
                 (second players-cards)))))
```

Use [`assoc-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in) and some [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring), something like this:

```
(defn share-card-to-player [game [player cards]]
  (assoc-in game [:players player :cards] cards))
```

Your next function:

```
(defn shuffle-and-share-cards [myshuffle game]
  (reduce share-card-to-player game
          (map vector
               (keys (get game :players))
               (->>  (get game :cards)
                     (myshuffle)
                     (partition (/ (count (get game :cards))
                                   (count (get game :players))))))))
```

You can also destructure hash-maps, so I would rewrite this as:

```
(defn shuffle-and-share-cards [{:keys [players cards] :as game}]
  (let [card-piles (->> cards
                        shuffle
                        (partition (/ (count cards)
                                      (count players))))]
    (reduce share-card-to-player game
            (map vector
                 (keys players)
                 card-piles))))
```

Next functions:

```
(defn announce [game]
  game)

(defn play-card [game curr-player]
  (println curr-player)
  (println game)

  (let [played-card (io/play-card-inp)]
    (->
     (assoc-in game [:players curr-player :cards]
               (remove #(= played-card %) (get-in game [:players curr-player :cards])))

     (assoc-in [:current-trick]
               (conj (game [:current-trick]) played-card)))))
```

`announce` is useless and [`update`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) and [`update-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) are better here:

```
(defn play-card [game curr-player]
  (println curr-player)
  (println game)
  (let [played-card (io/play-card-inp)]
    (-> game
        (update-in [:players curr-player :cards] #(remove #{played-card} %))
        (update :current-trick conj played-card))))
```

And finally, the last two functions:

```
(defn play-game-reduce []

  (let [game-init
        (->>
         (io/initialize-cards-and-players)
         (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
         (announce))

        play-round
        (reduce play-card (assoc-in game-init [:current-trick] '()) [:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4])]

    (reduce play-round game-init (range (get game-init :round-count)))))

(defn play-game []

  (let [game-init
        (->>
         (io/initialize-cards-and-players)
         (shuffle-and-share-cards io/myshuffle)
         (announce))]

    (loop [round 1 game game-init]

      (let [game-next (loop [curr-player 1 game-next game]
                        (if (> curr-player 4)
                          game-next
                          (recur (inc curr-player)
                                 (play-card game-next (keyword (str "p" curr-player))))))]

        (if (> round 2)
          game-next
          (recur (inc round) game-next))))))
```

`loop`/`recur` will be probably more readable, but two `reduce` should also work:

```
(defn play-game-reduce []
  (let [game-init (-> (io/new-game)
                      shuffle-and-share-cards)]
    (reduce (fn [game round]
              (reduce play-card (assoc-in game [:current-trick] '()) [:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4]))
            game-init
            (range (get game-init :round-count)))))

(play-game-reduce)
```

Version with one `reduce`:

```
(defn play-game-reduce []
  (let [game-init (-> (io/new-game)
                      shuffle-and-share-cards)
        turns (for [round (range (:round-count game-init))
                    player [:p1 :p2 :p3 :p4]]
                [round player])]
    (reduce (fn [game [round player]]
              (let [state (cond-> game
                                  (= player (:round-start-player game)) (assoc-in [:current-trick] '()))]
                (play-card state player)))
            game-init
            turns)))
```

And I also noticed that there's no validation of whether the current player can really play inserted card.

Comment: Wow, so many many thanks. That is so helpful.
Why would you not separate io from the rest? The reason for using not shuffle directly is, that i want that strict separation. What are the arguments to put shuffle into the function directly instead of inejcting it?

Comment: You can keep two separate files (`myio.clj` and `mymain.clj`), no problem with that. I don't see any point in defining `myshuffle` now, it's just renamed `shuffle`. Even with a different effect, you don't have to pass it as the argument, the resulting code will be a little bit simpler and shorter.

Comment: Wow, so helpful! I am still refactoring. So many gems. THank you @Martin Puda. How did you get so good?

Comment: There is an old joke:   Q: What is the definition of experience?  A: Knowing what not to do.    The corollary: Q: How do you know what not to do? A: I did it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I watched the talk (for the record, it gives a 5 minute overview of FP, then discusses error handling in pipelines in `F#`.

I didn't really care for the content of the video.

Clojure uses Exceptions for error handling, so a Clojure function always has only one output. Therefore the whole `bind` and `map` thing in the video doesn't apply.

I haven't looked at `F#` much before, but after watching that video I think it over-complicates things without much benefit.

Comment: I only briefly skimmed through the whole video, but it looks like a mediocre analogy trying to get you started on monadic composition. There are some ideas there that could usefully be applied to Clojure, but they're not very popular here, and it doesn't really cover the interesting cases anyway.

Comment: Yes, railway-oriented programming is all about monadic composition and error handling. If I'm not mistaken, there are some Clojure libraries that follow a monadic approach to error handling: cats, failjure, promenade.